# Is there a need of SQL server installed on Local for SSAS projects

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am pretty new to SSAS and have two very basic questions which are confusing me.

1. When we create a tabular or Multidimensional model project in Visual studio, do we we need to have SQL server installed on the same machine or it could work remotely.
2. Is it possible to install SQL Server with both tabular and Multidimensional mode. I am just practicing and my SQL server is installed in multidimensional mode. So i am not able to create tabular model in Visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SSAS only supports windows authentication, so you need to be on the same domain in which your SSAS server is, so that you can connect through windows authentication to the SSAS server, if this is not possible then you will have to install it locally.
2. You cannot have an instance of SSAS to be both tabular and multidimensional, but you can have separate instances installed on the same server for both multidimensional and tabular.

Answer (score 0):

1. No you don't need to have it installed, but you'll have to assign a Workspace server other than your localhost.
2. You have to install a new named Instance of SSAS as tabular. Connection string would be `MyServer\TabularInstanceName`